# Expected project/directory structure for Automake?

Tags: c, gnu, autotools, automake

I'm developing a static C library, and had been using a bare-bones Makefile.  We're now having to support offsite installs and whatnot, and the time has come to move to a more robust build standard.  I really want that to be autotools -- I love the automatic conformance to the GNU Build System and I also have found it pretty easy to work with.

That said, I have a problem.

Here's a rough outline of how the project has been structured:

```
project/
    common/
       pkg/
    inc/
    src/
       submodule1/
           some_thing/
           some_other_thing/
       submodule2/
        . . .
```

`common` contains header files that would be installed on a target system -- one header directly under common, and some other stuff in common/pkg.  (Well, it's not really pkg, that's just an example.)  Everything under `common` is `.h`.

`inc` contains internal include files that are strictly implementation-relevant and shouldn't be exposed.  Everything under `inc` is `.h`.

`src` has a directory for each of a number of submodules, and each of the submodules may or may not be divided into pieces (subsubmodules, if you want).  Everything under `src` is `.c`.

The original makefile would set a `SOURCES` variable consisting of every `.c` file found recursively in src, add `-I./common -I./inc`, build the object files, and archive them into a library.  Pretty straightforward.

Well, with automake, it doesn't seem so simple.  I figured out about adding flags to a build target, for instance `project_CPPFLAGS=-I./inc -I./common" -- this solves part of the problem, but I feel like I'm doing something wrong, somehow.

With those (suboptimal?) settings, I can get automake building and linking the library, which is exciting enough already, but the real reason I'm here is `make install`.

#### The main problem is this:

`common` contains the public interface to the library, if you will.  It is needed to build the sources, but it also needs to be installed.  If I include it from `project/`, then automake will see paths like `common/thing.h` and `common/pkg/other.h`, and get the paths wrong in `includedir` on installation.  I thought about having it recurse into that directory to build a project that only has installation headers, but that not only smells bad, it didn't work when I tried it.  The library headers need a specific tree structure -- **how do I maintain the lib header tree structure, make them available to all the source files, and install them rooted from `common`?**

Additionally, is there some more elegant way to handle includes than by forcing `-I`?  I know I have to specify them as `HEADERS` to get them in distribution packages, but that doesn't actually seem to make them available to be included, leaving me a bit lost.

I feel like automake (and perhaps GNU in general) is expecting some structure to my project that I'm just not seeing.  **If that's the case, please tell me** -- I'm perfectly willing to spend some time refactoring/reorganizing the project.  I really do feel like I'm missing some philosophical bit -- the current structure was designed without guidance or experience, and I am in no way attached to it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't use automake. Just don't. Everything it does is backwards and contrary to best practices. Autoconf is not so bad, but there's no reason to use automake. Just learn make and write your own makefile.

Comment: R., can you elaborate a bit?  I'm a very experienced coder (and pretty familiar with make) but a newcomer to deployment and build management; what best practices do you feel it violates?  Is it really better to write e.g. the install, uninstall, dist, clean, distclean, etc. targets by hand?

Comment: Make is a very simple but powerful dependency resolution system, and automake throws most of that power out and uses it as a dumb script system. The best description I've seen of the issue (not specific to automake but to misuse of make in general) is Recursive Make Considered Harmful: http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/

Comment: Those not understanding automake are doomed to reject it, and at times reinvent it.. poorly.

Comment: The autotools try to encapsulate nearly 20 years of platform inconsistencies, quirks, and missing functionality. Ugly problems sometimes need ugly solutions.

Comment: @R..: Modern automake supports non-recursive makefiles, JSYK. Add `subdir-objects` to your `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE` call and add `AM_PROG_CC_C_O` (if using C). Both go in `configure.ac`.

Comment: @Brett: 20 years ago that might have been useful, but nowadays the stuff they do is a lot more harmful than helpful. Especially gnulib which, while not required, is often used along with automake projects. The gnulib idea of "portability" is to have ugly hacks that poke at the internals of every known 1980s Unix implementation and the contemporary BSD and glibc internals, and abort the build with `#error` on any other system.

Comment: @Jack: That's nice, but the reason I cited that article was not only the traditional use of recursive make (or even worse, recursive configure) with automake, but also the fact that it explains very well the way make is intended to work and how almost everybody using it fails to take advantage of its main feature and instead uses it as a dumb script language. Automake is guilty of this in ways that extend far beyond recursive make invocation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not see anything wrong with using `-I`. It even allows to consistently use the very `#include <pkg/foo.h>` notation in both your tree, and third-party projects making use of pkg/foo.h.

```
AM_CPPFLAGS = -I${top_srcdir}/common -I${top_srcdir}/inc
```

To install the files in `common`, you can either utilize `SUBDIRS = common` (from toplevel `Makefile.am`),

```
# <top>/common/Makefile.am
nobase_include_HEADERS = pkg/foo.h pkg2/bar.h
```

or, if you choose to do a non-recursive approach, something like

```
# <top>/Makefile.am
xxxpkgdir = ${includedir}/pkg
xxxpkg_HEADERS = common/pkg/foo.h
xxxpkg2dir = ${includedir}/pkg2
xxxpkg2_HEADERS = common/pkg2/bar.h
```

Comment: Ah!  I was staring at the bit in the automake manual explaining how you could name new directories to use on the left, and my intuition was screaming at me, but I didn't put that together with path stripping on the right until you so helpfully demonstrated.  I had tried the recursive SUBDIR thing and had trouble with it, but I just set up something like your last example and it works perfectly.  Thanks!